# Magento 2 - Hide Products with no Images via PHP SQL Query

Tags: magento2, php, sql

I have an SQL query that i run on the database manually which checks the catalogue for products that do not have an image and hides them, i want to run this via cron so have created a php with the following content:

```
    <?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Script to run

$sql= 

update catalog_product_entity_int m;
left join eav_attribute a on a.entity_type_id = 4 and a.attribute_id = m.attribute_id
set value = 2
where
a.attribute_code = 'status'
and m.entity_id in
(
select m.entity_id
from catalog_product_entity m
left join catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity a
on a.entity_id = m.entity_id
where a.value_id is null
)
;

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

But I get this error: [PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'catalog_product_entity_int' (T_STRING) in /home/public_html/modimages/hideimages.php on line 20

The query works fine when i put it directly on phpmyadmin so i am guessing i am missing something very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the **quotes** (") in variable **$sql**. Try the below one.

```
$sql= "update catalog_product_entity_int m
left join eav_attribute a on a.entity_type_id = 4 and a.attribute_id = m.attribute_id
set value = 2
where
a.attribute_code = 'status'
and m.entity_id in
(
select m.entity_id
from catalog_product_entity m
left join catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity a
on a.entity_id = m.entity_id
where a.value_id is null
)";
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!